# What error should server respond with when client sends invalid uuid?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, httpresponse

I am developing microservice using spring boot. This service generates uuid and sends it to the client when he enters to app, and client saves uuid in cookie. Now when client makes request to resource there is a filter that check if uuid is valid.

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        String uuid = req.getParameter("guest_uuid");

        if (isValidUUID(uuid)){
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }else {
            // respond with customer error
        }

    }
```

What error should server respond with so that client side(javascript) could identify this error and remove uuid from cookie?

Comment: I think an invalid request parameter is covered by `400 Bad request`, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1

Comment: I would use AccessDenied or BadRequest with an ErrorResponse json containing an app specific error code and description.